# Sprite file loaded already is not referenced and instead a request is made for the same file

Tags: html, css

I have css like

```
.is--stratus .icon__nav-threats.is--gray {
     background: url('/resources/img/navIcons_RiskInsight.png') no-repeat -1px -41px;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
 }
.is--stratus .icon__nav-threats.is--blue {
    background: url('/resources/img/navIcons_RiskInsight.png') no-repeat -1px -83px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
 }
```

When I change the class name for the element from is--gray to is--blue it makes a new request for the same file. So the background image is loaded after a couple of seconds making the UI look like its broken.

Why is this happening? Does the way we load css into the page matter here? Im using webpack1 and this seems to happen only in the production build and not in the dev build. Do browsers not cache images loaded through js injected css??

Comment: You will be adding the images through the css after the page loads, I assume, which will mean you'll always see the sprites load after everything else. Can you inline these styles or put them in the regular stylesheet instead?

Comment: @NathanielFlick found the issue. It was cache control headers. Thanks.

Comment: Darn it, I was going to suggest that but didn't think it would help. Glad you found it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Its 'cache-control' property in the response headers. Webpack's dev server sets the response headers properly. But my tomcat server doesn't. Need to configure that properly.

**Dev server's cache setting**

[image: dev server's (Webpack's) cache setting]

**Prod server's (Tomcat's) cache setting**

[image: prod server's cache setting]